# Remove the GMT-#### text from a date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I would like to remove the "GMT-####" text from the results. Date/time results will differ based on the search criteria the user enters.

```
    for (var j = 0; j < resultCountGLM; j++) {

            var featureAttributes2 = results[1].features[j].attributes;
            //console.log(featureAttributes2)

            if (attr = "DATE_UTC") {
                attr1 = "Detected during the 1-hour period beginning"
                var dateGM = new Date(featureAttributes2[attr]);
                resultItems.push("<p class='reportTextResults_font'><b>" + attr1 + ":</b>  " + dateGM + "</p>");
            }
        }
        resultItems.push("<br>");
```

Example Output:

```
    Detected during the 1-hour period beginning: Thu Jan 02 2020 14:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
    Detected during the 1-hour period beginning: Thu Jan 02 2020 16:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
```

Desired Output:

```
    Detected during the 1-hour period beginning: Thu Jan 02 2020 14:00:00 (Central Standard Time)
    Detected during the 1-hour period beginning: Thu Jan 02 2020 16:00:00 (Central Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use vanilla javascript you have two options. Either remove it yourself or look at one of the `.toXXX` functions. Example:

```
new Date().toLocaleString()
//"1/14/2020, 1:05:58 PM"
```

If you need it to be exactly that or potentially more granularity down the line, there's lots of libraries out there that help with formatting dates.

Comment: Thanks the .toLocaleString is a possible option. I think I figured out how to replace the GMT text however.

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateGM = new Date(featureAttributes2[attr]).toString().split(" ");
dateGM.splice(5,1) //remove GMT-####
dateGM.join(" ");
resultItems.push("<p class='reportTextResults_font'><b>" + attr1 + ":</b>  " + dateGM + "</p>");
```

Comment: This results in a date format like so without time: Thu,Jan,02,2020

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way if you need only the date and I give a different option because local time  may affect the results.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


 <p id="demo4"></p>
<p id="demo5"></p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
   
<script>
var dateGM = new Date('Thu Jan 02 2020 14:00:00 GMT-0600');
var pre='GMT'

var date = dateGM.toString().slice(0, dateGM.toString().lastIndexOf(pre));

var myDate = new Date(date);
    var    dateString=dateGM.toISOString().split('t')[0];
 var dateString1=dateGM.toISOString();

 var dateString2=dateGM.toISOString().split('T')[0];
 var dateString3=dateGM.toISOString().split('.')[0]    
 var dateStringnew  =dateGM.toDateString('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')+" "+dateGM.toLocaleTimeString('it-IT');   
//console.log(dateStringnew);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dateString;
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = dateString1;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = dateString2;
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = dateString3;
document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = date;
document.getElementById("demo5").innerHTML = dateStringnew;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Your code can be

```
 for (var j = 0; j < resultCountGLM; j++) {

            var featureAttributes2 = results[1].features[j].attributes;
            //console.log(featureAttributes2)

            if (attr = "DATE_UTC") {
                attr1 = "Detected during the 1-hour period beginning"
                var dateGM = new Date(featureAttributes2[attr]);
                 var pre='GMT'

             var date = 
        dateGM.toString().slice(0,dateGM.toString().lastIndexOf(pre));
                resultItems.push("<p class='reportTextResults_font'><b>" + attr1 + ":</b>  " + date + "</p>");
            }
        }
        resultItems.push("<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with the following below. The GMT text will always be 8 characters.

```
    var dateGM = new Date(featureAttributes2[attr]);
    var stringGM = dateGM.toString();
    var n = stringGM.indexOf("GMT")
    var dateGMfinal = stringGM.replace(stringGM.substring(n,n+8)," ")
```